# Deactivating all "ready/running Tasks" on a bunch of servers in Specific Folders with the ability to activate those tasks again

Tags: powershell, task, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

i am looking for a Powershell script that can disable all tasks that are "ready" or "running" in a specific folder in the Task Scheduler on 3 or more servers.

After we updated the software i should be able to activate all the tasks that were disabled by the script again, not just activate all disabled scripts, but specificly the ones that were disabled by the script.

I know this should be possible, but i am not capable of assembling the single parts. Everything thats more than a single command is to much for my logic capacitys.

Comment: "Everything thats more than a single command is to much for my logic capacitys." - then start there - with a single command - see how far it takes you. Once you hit a wall, come back and ask _specific_ questions about the problems you're facing :)

Comment: Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath \xxx\ | Where {($_.State -like "running") -or ($_.State -like "ready")

Thats what i got, but i dont know anything about piping the results to another command or how i can put this command into an remote command.

Answer (score 0):

```
<#getScheduledTasksinfo-FreeholdReboots.ps1
.Synopsis
   PowerShell script to list all Scheduled Tasks, the User ID and the State
.DESCRIPTION
   This script scans the content of the c:\Windows\System32\tasks and searches the UserID XML value. 
   The output of the script is a comma-separated log file containing the Computername, Task name, UserID, Status.
.Author
   UNKNOWN
.Tweaker
   Patrick Burwell
#>

Remove-Item -Force "D:\batch\Logs\Maintenance\$day-SchedTasks-Reboots.csv"
$logfilepath = "D:\batch\Logs\Maintenance\$day-SchedTasks-Reboots.csv"
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

$serverlist = gc D:\batch\input\servers.txt

foreach($server in $serverlist){
    if($server -like '#*')
    {
        continue
    }
    Write-Host $server

    $path = "\\" + $server + "\c$\Windows\System32\Tasks"
    $tasks = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File

    if ($tasks)
    {
        Write-Verbose -Message "I found $($tasks.count) tasks for $server"
    }

    foreach ($item in $tasks)
    {
        if($item -like 'Optimize Start Menu*'){continue}
        if ($item -like "User_Feed_Synchronization*"){continue}
        if($item -like 'ComputeSensorWatchDog*'){continue}
        if ($item -like "Google*"){continue}
        $AbsolutePath = $path + "\" + $item.Name
        $task = [xml] (Get-Content $AbsolutePath)
        $states = (Get-ScheduledTask -Verbose -TaskPath '\' -TaskName "reboot")
        [STRING]$check = $task.Task.Principals.Principal.UserId
        [STRING]$state = $states.State
        if ($task.Task.Principals.Principal.UserId)
        {
        if($item -ilike "*reboot*"){
          Write-Verbose -Message "Writing the log file with values for $server"           
          Add-content -path $logfilepath -Value "$server,$item,$check,$state"
        }
        else {continue}
        }

    }
}
```